# Automatically reconnecting to SSH with iTerm2 and tmux integration

Tags: ssh, tmux, iterm2

I am SSHing into a remote server with tmux using iTerm's tmux integration as so:

```
ssh $myhost -t "tmux -CC a -t main || tmux -CC new -A -s main"
```

However, when I walk away from my mac for 30 seconds, it goes to sleep and the internet connection is broken. This causes all my tabs to be frozen or sometimes it detaches.

```
** tmux mode started **

Command Menu
----------------------------
esc    Detach cleanly.
  X    Force-quit tmux mode.
  L    Toggle logging.
  C    Run tmux command.
Unrecognized command from tmux. Did your ssh session die? The command was:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Detached
```

If frozen, I have to press shift-X to force-quit tmux mode. In any case, I have to manually rerun `ssh $myhost -t "tmux -CC a -t main || tmux -CC new -A -s main"` which takes a few seconds and ruins my productivity for the day.

Is there a way to make iTerm automatically reconnect if the network is broken?

Please note: using Eternal Terminal is not an option because I do not have sudo access on the remote server. Using mosh is not an option either.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I haven't found an answer for this yet

Comment: I found a solution that works for me. Have a look at autossh. I just use that to connect instead of ssh and when I open my laptop after sleeping all the connections come back up. with tmux and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

Install autossh and use it like this:

`autossh -M 0 mymachine -A -t tmux attach-session`

Where `mymachine` can be something in your ssh config. Alternative just do `user@ip`

The tmux part assumes you have a single session open on that machine, if not you can just supply a name. The -A is just a passthrough option to let your ssh agent sign stuff, eg git pulls from a remote server. I also don't bother with the iTerm tmux integration, since I can now just have a tab that has the remote tmux screen in it all the time.

I found by doing this I only need to write the command once, and I'm back logged into all my remote tmux sessions each time I open the terminal, eg after I open the machine after sleeping.